# Algorithm for finding area of all rectangles

Tags: algorithm

Lets say we get rectangles in form of 4 points: their (x1, y1), ..., (x4, y4)
We want to calculate the total area they cover. We want to count the total area, if more rectangles overlap, we count this area only once.

I'm not really looking for finished solution, pseudocode or some links to algorithms and data structures useful here would be appreciated.

the form of rectangles is: given by three integers: left position, right position and height. for example:

L:0 R:2 H:2

L:1 R:3 H:3

L:-1 R:4 H:1

total area would be: 10

the max value for x axis is from -1e9 to 1e9, starts at x=L and ends at x=R
y cannot be lower than 0 and always starts at y=0 and ends at y=H

Comment: This question may be more suitable for the [**Math StackExchange**](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your question is not clear, are talking about discretization of rectangles or what? In general if rectangle R1 has **ordered** (say bottom left to upper right) coordinates x11,y11, x12,y12 and R2 x21,y21, x22,y22 then if they overlaps (x21<x12 && y21<y12) then total area is the sum of areas minus overlapping, thus A(R1)+A(R2)-A(x21,y21;x12,y12).

Comment: Are all your rectangles axis-aligned (y1 = y2; y3 = y4; x2 = x3 and x1 = x4)? Do you have many rectangles? Then simple block-filling with coordinate compression could be useful.

Comment: What's the desired complexity?

Comment: It should be able to calculate 1e5 rectangles under a few seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These rectangles have their base at y=0? I'm assuming that's true. So these are like buildings in a city viewed from a distance. You're trying to trace the skyline.

Store the rectangles in one array so you can use the array indices as unique IDs. Represent each left and right rectangle edge as an "event" that includes the ID for the rectangle it belongs to and the x-coordinate of the corresponding edge. Put all the events in a list EL and sort by x-coordinate.  Finally you'll need a dynamically sorted set (e.g. a Java TreeSet) of rectangle IDs sorted by corresponding rectangle height descending. It's called SL, the "sweep line".  Due the way it's sorted, SL.first is always the ID of the highest rectangle currently referenced by the SL.

Now you can draw the outline of the collection of rectangles as follows:

```
SL = <empty>  // sweep line
x0 = EL.first.left // leftmost x among all rectangle edges
lastX = x0
for each event E in EL // process events left-to-right
  Let y0 = if SL.isEmpty then 0 else SL.first.height // current y
  if E.ID in SL // event in SL means sweep line is at rectangle's right edge
    remove E.ID from SL
  else // event means sweep line is a new rectangle's left edge
    add E.ID to SL
  Let y1 = if SL.isEmpty then 0 else SL.first.height // new y
  if y1 != y0
    output line seg (lastX, y0) -> (E.x, y0)
    output line seg (E.x, y0) -> (E.x, y1)
    lastX = E.x
output final line seg (lastX, 0) -> (x0, 0)
```

Because this sounds like homework or maybe an interview question, I'll let you revise this algorithm to provide the area of the swept-out shape rather than drawing its edge.

**Addition**

Just for fun:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.Integer.compare;
import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static java.util.Collections.sort;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class SkyLine {
  static class Rectangle {
    final int left;
    final int right;
    final int height;
    Rectangle(int left, int right, int height) {
      this.left = left;
      this.right = right;
      this.height = height;
    }
  }
  static class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
    final int x;
    final int id;
    public Event(int x, int id) {
      this.x = x;
      this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event e) { return compare(x, e.x); }
  }

  final List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();  
  final Comparator byHeightDescending = 
      (Comparator<Integer>) (Integer a, Integer b) -> 
          compare(rectangles.get(b).height, rectangles.get(a).height);
  final SortedSet<Integer> scanLine = new TreeSet<>(byHeightDescending);
  final List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

  SkyLine(Rectangle [] data) {
    stream(data).forEach(rectangles::add);
    int id = 0;
    for (Rectangle r : rectangles) {
      events.add(new Event(r.left, id));
      events.add(new Event(r.right, id));
      ++id;
    }
    sort(events);
  }

  int area() {
    int area = 0;
    Event ePrev = null;
    for (Event e : events) {
      if (ePrev != null) area += (e.x - ePrev.x) * rectangles.get(scanLine.first()).height;
      if (!scanLine.remove(e.id)) scanLine.add(e.id);
      ePrev = e;
    }
    return area;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Rectangle [] data = {
      new Rectangle(0, 2, 2),
      new Rectangle(1, 3, 3),
      new Rectangle(-1, 4, 1),
    };
    int area = new SkyLine(data).area();
    System.out.println(area);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, Saying that I'm trying to trace the skyline was enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that your rectangles have integer coordinates in a very small range, say 0 to 10. Then an easy approach is to create a grid and paint the rectangles onto it:

[image: Unit coordinate grid]

The occupied "pixels" could be stored in a set or they could be set bits in a bitmap. When rectangles overlap, the intersection is just marked as occupied again and so contributes only once the the area. The area is the number of occupied cells.

For large dimensions, the data structures would become too big. Also, painting a rectangle that is several million pixels wide would be slow.

But the technique can still be applied when we use compressed coordinates. Your grid then has only the coordinates that are actual coordinates of the rectangles. The cells have variable widths and heights. The number of cells depends on the number of rectangles, but it is independent of the minimum and maximum coordinates:

[image: Compressed coordinate grid]

The algorithm would look like this:

- Find all unique *x* coordinates. Sort them in ascending order and store (coordinate, index) pairs in a dictionary for easy look-up.
- Do the same for the *y* coordinates.
- Paint the rectangles: Find the indices of *x* and *y* ranges and occupy the cells between them.
- Calculate the area by summing the area of all occupied cells.